# Чи можна "їсти молоко"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Нещодавно я почув як одна дівчина сказала, що йде "їсти молоко". І на моє зауваження, що його не їдять, а п'ють, вона відповіла, що правильний лише перший варіант.

Вирішив пошукати в Інтернеті — і справді, є такі варіанти. Ось, наприклад:

> Коли краще їсти молоко (сайт [Ukr.media](https://ukr.media/medicine/352404/))
>
> У піст не можна їсти молоко, яйця та вироби, що їх містять (сайт [1.zt.ua](https://www.1.zt.ua/themes/rizne/u-pist-ne-mozhna-yisti-moloko-yaytsya-ta-virobi-shcho-yih-mistyat.html), хоча гадаю, що можливо тут йдеться про молочні продукти)

Цікавить, чи справді можна так сказати, чи все ж краще надавати перевагу звичному "пити молоко"?